# Flask stormpath registration page gives strange error

Tags: python, flask, stormpath

I was following this tutorial on how to create a user authentification system on flask, which lacks this, using stormpath and this tutorial (https://stormpath.com/blog/build-a-flask-app-in-30-minutes); after trying it out and feeling content with it i tried looking into enabling registration by setting

```
app.config['STORMPATH_ENABLE_REGISTRATION'] = False
```

to True in the flaskr.py file; enabling the default stormpath registration page, but on connecting to localhost/register it gives me this long error i can't make heads or tails of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1994, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask_stormpath\views.py", line 39, in register
form = RegistrationForm(config=current_app.config)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\wtforms\form.py", line 212, in __call__
return type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask_stormpath\forms.py", line 40, in __init__
**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask_wtf\form.py", line 158, in __init__
    super(Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 7 were given
```

I have absolutely no idea what's going wrong and i can't find anything in the documentation or similar errors.

Answer (score 0):

When you run into a Python stacktrace, start at the bottom and work your way up:

```
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask_wtf\form.py", line 158, in __init__
    super(Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 7 were given
```

This indicates that a function from `form.py` is being used incorrectly.  Since `form.py` is part of flask-wtf and you're unlikely to have modified it (I hope!), keep going up:

```
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask_stormpath\views.py", line 39, in register
form = RegistrationForm(config=current_app.config)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\wtforms\form.py", line 212, in __call__
return type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask_stormpath\forms.py", line 40, in __init__
**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask_wtf\form.py", line 158, in __init__
    super(Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 7 were given
```

Here's the more likely candidate: `RegistrationForm(config=current_app.config)` on line 39 of `views.py` is being called incorrectly or in a way WTForms wasn't expecting.  It's probably the `config=current_app.config`.

If at all possible, import variables from your application config from form**s**.py and do your form configuration there before using it in `views.py`.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you are using Flask-WTF version 0.14 or greater (some changes were introduced in this version that are not compatible with the previous version). This explains why the stacktrace mentions `flask_wtf`:

```
File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask_wtf\form.py", line 158, in __init__
    super(Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 7 were given
```

The problem has been fixed in the `develop` branch of stormpath-flask but has not been released yet. If you can not wait for an official release, take a look at the changes detailed [in this pull request](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-flask/pull/90/files). To fix the problem, just implement, in you local flask-stormpath installation, the changes shown in `flask_stormpath/forms.py` in the pull request.

So in your case, you would:

1. `cd` into you the `C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask_stormpath`
   directory (we know this based on the stacktrace you received).
2. Open `forms.py` and make the changes shown in the pull request
   linked above

See [here](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-flask/issues/92) for a discussion on the topic.